# Are questions about specific legal agreements off topic?

Tags: discussion

[Am I allowed to blog about technical topics I was paid to learn about?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6739/am-i-allowed-to-blog-about-technical-topics-i-was-paid-to-learn-about)

It seems to me that the answer to his question would depend on the terms of whatever contract he has with his employer. Obviously, no one can really answer that without seeing the full text of the contract, and even if he was allowed to post it, I think the question would be too specific to be of value to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used to close questions like that. But realized that these questions are how we thrive.

This used to be known as the *Too localized* reason. We abolished this because all questions should be accepted, regardless of their applicability to others. We should be able to accept any question, from any audience.

If the issue with the question was that there wasn't enough information, and was not objectionable answerable, it should be closed as *too broad*, or *unclear what you are asking*. Or just down vote and move on.